# Which is SurrealDB's 'default' secret when signing JWTs created by the SIGNIN method?

Tags: jwt, surrealdb

Which secret does SurrealDB use to sign JWTs returned by the `SIGNIN` method if no `DEFINE TOKEN [...]` is provided?

I suppose it is a dynamically generated one, but which is the algorithm/strategy used to generated it?

Thanks

```
DEFINE TABLE user SCHEMAFULL
    PERMISSIONS
        FOR select, update, delete WHERE id = $auth.id;

DEFINE FIELD name ON user TYPE string;
DEFINE FIELD email ON user TYPE string ASSERT is::email($value);
DEFINE FIELD password ON user TYPE string;

DEFINE INDEX email ON user FIELDS email UNIQUE;
```

```
DEFINE SCOPE user SESSION 1d
    SIGNIN (
        SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = $email AND crypto::argon2::compare(password, $password)
    )
    SIGNUP (
        CREATE user CONTENT {
            name: $name,
            email: $email,
            password: crypto::argon2::generate($password)
        }
    );
```

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -d '{"NS":"test", "DB":"test", "SC":"user", "name":"John Doe", "email":"john@doe.org", "password":"VerySecurePassword!"}' \
    http://localhost:8000/signup
```

With which secret is the JWT created during the execution of the code below?

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -d '{"NS":"test", "DB":"test", "SC":"user", "email":"john@doe.org", "password":"VerySecurePassword!"}' \
    http://localhost:8000/signin
```

Answer (score 0):

`HS512` is the default algorithm.

You can also see the other alternatives here: https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/statements/define/token

Will update this page so that it specifies the default algorithm